# Oracle XE 21c listener won't start

Tags: oracle, centos

I've installed Oracle XE 21c on a CentOS virtual machine, and when I try to start the listener this error message pops up:

```
[root@192 ~]# sudo /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin/lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 04-AUG-2022 15:47:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12545: Message 12545 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00515: Message 515 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

This is my env:

```
[root@192 ~]# env
LC_PAPER=es_UY.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=14
LC_ADDRESS=es_UY.UTF-8
HOSTNAME=192.168.50.253
LC_MONETARY=es_UY.UTF-8
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.122.1 55502 22
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
LC_NUMERIC=es_UY.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=root
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/lib
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
LC_TELEPHONE=es_UY.UTF-8
ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_UY.UTF-8
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_UY.UTF-8
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.122.1 55502 192.168.50.253 22
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE
LC_TIME=es_UY.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_UY.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

As you can see the ORACLE variables are set, as well as the TNS_ADMIN and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
This is how my listener.ora looks like:

```
[root@192 ~]# cat /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
# OLD IP = 10.0.2.15

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

My tnsnames.ora:

```
[root@192 ~]# cat /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
```

And of course the service is running:

```
[root@192 ~]# systemctl -l status oracle-xe-21c
● oracle-xe-21c.service - SYSV: This script is responsible for taking care of configuring the RPM Oracle XE Database and its associated services.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/oracle-xe-21c; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since jue 2022-08-04 14:53:57 -03; 59min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5588 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/oracle-xe-21c stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6027 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/oracle-xe-21c start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

ago 04 14:53:57 192.168.50.253 systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: This script is responsible for taking care of configuring the RPM Oracle XE Database and its associated services....
ago 04 14:53:57 192.168.50.253 oracle-xe-21c[6027]: The Oracle Database instance XE is already started.
ago 04 14:53:57 192.168.50.253 systemd[1]: Started SYSV: This script is responsible for taking care of configuring the RPM Oracle XE Database and its associated services..
```

So I don't know what's wrong, I've tried resetting my environment variables multiple times, going back to the default tnsnames and listener files (I just modified the host as I needed to access it from my host PC).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Database and listener should never be run as root. You should have a dedicated account for that, with all the environment set for that user.

Comment: I've created an Oracle user and set the environment variables. I tried to start the listener and this was the output: `Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
   Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted` I'm guessing I need to give it permissions but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I was running the database and listener as root since it's an academic environment and not a production one, I didn't think it'd have a negative effect.

Comment: @F.Carratto Some oracle services - like the listener - specifically *cannot* run as root. Always follow the installation instructions exactly. Sounds like your configuration may need to be re-installed and owned/run as the correct user.

Comment: That's weird... I was running as root without issues before. Something happened when I turned off the machine and then this happened.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you exported the Oracle environment variables, or just set them?

Comment: I exported them yeah. It just doesn't want to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

After following @pmdba's instructions, I re-installed the VM and thus the database, this time using a non-root user named "ora". It worked like a charm. I added the exact same variables to my .bash_profile instead of exporting them and now I can even use sqlplus, which was impossible in the previous working set-up I had. Thanks.

Comment: Then again, restarting the machine produces the same issue. `TNS-00511: No listener Linux Error 111: Connection refused`